# Why am I having this error on my terminal using kali linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having an issues when opening my terminal on my **Visual Studio Code**. It is giving me this error message:

> The terminal shell path "/usr/local/bin/fish" does not exist" am using
>   a kali linux os.

Comment: Probably because fish is not installed ?!?

Comment: Did you install `fish`? And are you sure you need Kali Linux?

Comment: yes, i did install fish on my system @Marged

Comment: @RomeoNinov please what is or are your opinion on this error have been using kali linux for almost a year now

Comment: What is the result of command `ls -l /usr/local/bin/fish` and `file /usr/local/bin/fish`. Kali is very specialized distribution, not suitable for non experienced people (no offense)

Comment: @RomeoNinov no offense taken.. the result for the first command is ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/fish': No such file or directory
and for the second command is /usr/local/bin/fish: cannot open `/usr/local/bin/fish' (No such file or directory)

Comment: So you do not have this file on this place. Try with `which fish` to find it and edit visual studio config and change the path

Answer (score 0):

As per comments you do not have `fish` on the location you mention: `/usr/local/bin/fish`. So you need to find where this file is located:

```
which fish
```

or if you do not have it in path

```
find / -name fish -type f
```

and then edit the configuration of visual studio